# Acessando Lista de outra classe

Tags: java

Tenho uma classe Armazemque contem uma lista de produtos, como seria a interação dessa lista na classe gerencia utilizando o método retornaProduto() sem parâmetros. Na saída do meu código está dando null.

Classe Armazen

```
public class Armazem {
  List<Produto> produtos;

  Armazen(){
        this.produto = new ArrayList<Produto>();    
  }
  public void adicionarProduto(Produto p) {
            produtos.add(p);    
  }
  public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
  }
```

Classe Gerencia

```
public class Gerencia{
    Armazen a = new Armazen();
    private String N_estoque;
   
    public Gerencia(String N_estoque) {
       this.N_estoque = N_estoque;  
   }
   public  Gerencia retornaProdutos() { 
       for(Armazen pdto : a.getProdutos()) 
              System.out.println("esses são os produtos"+ pdto);
    
}


  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Produto arroz = new Produto("Arroz");
       Gerencia gerencia = arroz.retornaProdutos();
      System.out.println("Em estoque: " + gerencia);
```

}

Comment: Se alguem puder me ajudar nessa.

Comment: Minha grande dificultade é em entender como usar uma lista que foi populada em outra classe, já tentei criar uma reférência para classe tipo( List<outraClasse>  outraClasse; ), e não consegui, já procurei alguns exemplos mas ainda não consegui entender.

Comment: Olá  amigo, obrigado pela atenção, foi só erro de digitação mesmo pois fiz no celular essa postagem, mesmo com this.produtos está retornando null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No construtor da classe `Armazen`, você está usando `this.produto` e não `this.produtos`, pois a variável declarada nessa classe é `produtos`, e não `produto`.

No seu método de `retornaProdutos` na classe `Gerencia` você deveria retornar `void` ou fazer um retorno de acordo com o que quer. E dentro dos parâmetros do `for`, você deveria fazer `Produto pdto : a.getProdutos()`, pois cada elemento retornado de `a.getProdutos()` é um `Produto`, e não um `Armazen`.

E no caso essa sua lógica de salvar o retorno de `retornaProdutos` dentro de uma variável e depois retorna-la dentro de uma String não irá funcionar, pois você não está retornando uma lista.

Além disso, no método main você não está adicionando nenhum produto na lista.

Suponde que você importou `ArrayList` e `List` corretamente, e a classe `Produto` existir, acredito que o seu código irá funcionar corretamente com essas alterações.

Comment: Obrigado amigo vou fazer as alterações que você me indicou.